# How to count generated random numbers satisfying a certain property?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I would like to simulate a simple coin throwing game: I throw a (fair) coin a certain number of times and want to count how many heads I obtain in total. Let i denote the number of times I throw the coin, and j the number of heads I get. Let 0 represent Heads and 1 represent tails.

```
{
    int j = 0;

    srand(time(nullptr));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << rand() % 2 << endl;
        if (rand() % 2 == 0)
        {
            j = j + 1;
        }
    }
    cout << j << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output value for j however is not what I expect; say I get 111 (i.e. three tails), then I would expect j=0; however, what is actually produced is different, and changes every time I compile (say I get j=2, next time j=1, and so on).

Comment: you're generating two different numbers with `rand()`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the fragment

```
    cout << rand()%2 << endl;
    if (rand() % 2 == 0) {
```

You call `rand()` twice, so the displayed number and the number used for the `if` are not the same. Try

```
    r=rand();
    cout << r%2 << endl;
    if (r % 2 == 0) {
```

after declaring r

**EDIT**

Just to make that clear: The variable assignment is to be done INSIDE the loop, as in

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    r=rand();
    cout << r%2 << endl;
    ...
```

Comment: Trying your suggestion either gives a list of 1's or 0's (for cout<<r%2) @Eugen Rieck

Comment: @Star_Watcher `rand()%2` will always give you either `0` or `1`. That's what you are using in your original code

Comment: I meant that trying Eugen's suggestion, I ALWAYS either a) get a list of 1's repeating, i.e. 1111... or b) a list of zeroes, i.e. 00000.... So it's not "random" anymore  @Fureeish

Comment: @Star_Watcher I highly doubt that unless you incorrectly implemented Eugen's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks - I corrected my code. Previously I had the line r=rand() outside the loop, that's why it did not work. @Fureeish